# Bot one to one chat

Tags: node.js, telegraf

I've created a telegram bot with some logic. The user put his request, the bot sends the response. But if there is more then 1 user in the chat, everyone see messages of other, as well as they see messages of the bot. So my question is how can I make it private?

Comment: I don't think so. When you chat in a group, literally everyone can see the message. There's no way to hide it. Perhaps you can just design the bot that **a private chat**, a.k.a **DM** will be initiated with the user who used a specific command.

Comment: Just separate bot command into **private**, and **public** based. For example, if a command like `/play a game` which is **multiplayer-based**. Then you should code it for group, and public usage based. Whereas for a command like, `/show my info` which is **private based**. Then the bot should only send the reply back to the user's DM box.